# App badge doesn't change when using PushKit framework pushes

Tags: ios, objective-c, notifications, apple-push-notifications, pushkit

Since I switched to using `PushKit` framework for application, there are no app badge changes on push received.

Changes to APNS implementation I've done to use `PushKit` :

- On server side, I replaced APNS certificates with VOIP push certificates.
- On client side, I replaced:

  1. `registerForRemoteNotifications` with

     ```
     PKPushRegistry *pushRegistry = [[PKPushRegistry alloc] initWithQueue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];

     pushRegistry.delegate = (AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
     pushRegistry.desiredPushTypes = [NSSet setWithObject:PKPushTypeVoIP];`
     ```
  2. `didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken` and `didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError` with `didUpdatePushCredentials`
  3. `didReceiveRemoteNotification` and `didReceiveRemoteNotification FetchComplitionHandler` with `didReceiveIncomingPushWithPayload`

As a result, `didReceiveIncomingPushWithPayload` gets called, and I see valid badge number in payload dictionary, but, unfortunately app badge doesn't change.

Answer (score 0):

In your method `didReceiveRemoteNotification`, you should update the badge number yourself by setting it like this:

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
{
    [application setApplicationIconBadgeNumber:1];
}
```

Comment: when I used APNS and `didReceiveRemoteNotification`, app badge was set automatically, now I'm using `didReceiveIncomingPushWithPayload` from PK framework, and expected the same behaviour.

Comment: Well you can still use `setApplicationIconBadgeNumber` to set the badge number. If it doesn't set it automatically you can make if statements to figure out what the number should be?

Comment: Yes, I can do it manually, but I thought that it should be done automatically, I  see that badge number come valid from server

Comment: So take that payload and then set the badge number? IDK whats so difficult lol :P https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/PushKit/Reference/PKPushPayload_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/PKPushPayload/dictionaryPayload